# iPhone Icons retina/normal with Ending: @2x.png

Tags: iphone, icons, uitabbarcontroller

My question is about TabBar-Icons: 
I define standartsized TabBarIcons (20x20) and for retina resolution I'll just add the same image in big (40x40) and name it xxx@2.png.

Thats it, Am I right ?

cheers Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Retina display has double the screen resolution (640px x 960px). Appending the `@2x` at the end of the image filename will allow the iPhone 4 to use those images instead.

Apple Developer Article:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe Apple recommends that tabbar icons be 30x30 (xxx.png) and 60x60 (xxx@2x.png). The names are correct.